# How to initialize an angularjs module by passing values/configurations

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm new to Angular and I'm from jQuery background.

My question is **How to initialize angularjs module by passing values/configurations**. Here is the scenario.

1. We will have core module (which will load/integrate other modules based on the need)
2. We're planned to create a module for each major feature
3. We need to load the module's based on the need

The only one approach till now I'm able to figure out is below,

1. Creating a custom attribute/tag directive
2. Create a custom controller to initialize the module
3. Create a new variable in the $scope and specify the configuration options

With this approach I'm able to access the options specified in the controller scope using the link function in the directive. The code is something like below,

```
// Main angular module
angular.module('myApp').directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            configOptions: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attribute) {
            // configurations will be available in scope.configOptions
            console.log(scope.configOptions);
        }

    };

});

// Module & Controller to initialize the main module.

angular.module('consumerApp', ['myApp']).controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.configOptions= {
        path: "xxxxx",
        height: xxx,
        width: xxx
    };

}]);

// HTML code
<div ng-controller='HomeCtrl'>  
    <div myDirective></div>
</div>
```

Is this valid/best approach or do we have better solutions to achieve the same. On further note is there any way available to initialize the app like we do in jQuery.